# Irreducible unitary representations of discrete abelian groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, unitary-representations

It seems to me that the statement below should be true but I would like to double-check.

**Statement:** Let $H$ be a (separable) complex Hilbert space and consider its associated unitary group $U(H)$ which we view simply as an discrete group (usually this group is turned into a topological group using the strong topology). Let $A$ be a discrete abelian group and let $\rho:A\rightarrow U(H)$ be a plain group homomorphism (so just an abstract group homomorphism since no topology is involved). Assume furthermore that the only closed $\rho(A)$-invariant subspaces of $H$ are $\{0\}$ and $H$. Then $\rho(A)\subseteq \mathbb{C}\cdot Id_H$.

**Q:** If the above statement is true, are there some useful generalizations which have a similar flavor ?

Comment: The standard word is "discrete" rather than "abstract". Actually once $A$ is assumed discrete, discussing on the topology of $U(H)$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Anyway this is true (without assuming $H$ separable), and is largely documented (see any book treating Pontryagin duality or abstract harmonic analysis such as Hewitt-Ross or Bekka-Harpe-Valette's appendix).

Comment: Thanks YCor for your comments. Is it possible to replace the group U(H) by something else that would contain scalar matrices ? I'm asking since the fact that the elements of U(H) are bounded operators on H is may be not so essential since afterall we give to U(H) the discrete topology.

Comment: I'll change the words abstract for discrete to conform to the usual terminology.